# What is wrong with the following java reflect code?

Tags: java

I'm trying to call URLClassLoader with reflect methods,

I checked the documents there's a constructor declared,

```
URLClassLoader(URL[] urls)
```

But the following code causes a `wrong number of arguments` exception:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getMethod("newInstance", URL[].class);
            URLClassLoader loader = (URLClassLoader) method.invoke (
                    new Object [] { new URL ("http://127.0.0.1/a.class") });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Method#invoke` takes two parameters, an "instance" variable, which refers to the instance of the object to invoke the method on and a "varargs" which represents the parameters, you are invoking the method on the `Object[]` array, which is invalid, perhaps you should try `URLClassLoader loader = (URLClassLoader) method.invoke (null, new Object [] { new URL[]{new URL ("http://127.0.0.1/a.class") }});` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a single `URL` object in place of an array of `URL`s

You need to create an array with one `URL`, and put that array inside `Object[]` array:

```
URLClassLoader loader = (URLClassLoader) method.invoke (
    new Object [] {
        new URL[] { new URL ("http://127.0.0.1/a.class") }
    });
```